# Como organizar array para exibir no gráfico (chart)

Tags: php, jquery

Esse gráfico tem como objetivo listar o total de acessos mensais por tipo de usuário do ano atual.

Ele é divido em 3 séries, cada série representa um tipo de usuário, dentro dela tem o total de acessos daquele tipo por mês:

```
labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
series: [
    [100, 200, 120, 280, 150, 300, 350, 200, 180, 350, 420, 500], // Total Access Users
    [80, 150, 100, 180, 80, 250, 150, 280, 360, 450, 520, 650], // Total artists
    [30, 80, 40, 90, 50, 100, 70, 160, 220, 240, 280, 350], // total studios
]
```

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
    public function get_monthly_accesses() {

        $current_year = date('Y');
        $responseseries = array();
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                $query = "select count(date_login) as accesses from user_access as ua
inner join user_details as ud on ud.user = ua.user
inner join user as u on ua.user = u.id
where type = {$j} AND YEAR(date_login) = {$current_year} AND MONTH(date_login) = {$i}";

                $total = $this->db->query($query)->result()[0]->accesses;
                $responseseries[] = $total;
            }

        }

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(json_encode($responseseries));
        echo '</pre>';
        die;

        return json_encode($responseseries);
    }
```

O retorno é esse:

```
string(147) "["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","7","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","13","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","10","0"]"
```

Não estou conseguindo dividir esse array em 3 para exibir no gráfico.

Comment: Se vc agrupar sua sql pelo tipo de usuário não resolveria? pq no final seu array deve ter pelo menos outros 3 arrays com 12 posições. Esses for encadeados eu não entendi...

Comment: então eu tiraria o where type e agrupo pelo tipo de user? mas e o for de 3 posicoes q eu criei, vai servir só para montar as series?

Comment: Sem mexer na consulta mude `$responseseries[] = $total` para `$responseseries[$j][] = $total` veja como é montado o array.

Comment: Nossa praticamente deu certo, o array foi divido em 3, só que tá mostrando a posição dele no json veja https://pastebin.com/VMcG2aGy

Comment: Mais qual o problema? não entendi.

Comment: Consegui rray, muito obrigado! eu só fui chamando o response no ajax pela posição do array dentro das series: series: [
            response[1],
            response[2],
            response[3],
        ]

Comment: Então por algum motivo seu retorno está sendo um objeto, quando deveria ser um array. Tem mais alguma coisa nesse código php? seu json deveria ser algo como `[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,13,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0]]` veja que o caraceter inicial é um colchete e não uma chave.

Comment: Sim o retorno do json deveria ser esse que você citou, no meu código php não tem mais nada, é só esse método mesmo.